# What symptoms can I expect from two broken teeth on a chainring?

Tags: chainring

Dealing with chain skipping (but mostly on the smaller chainrings, truth be told) I've wondered how these affect the riding and how many problems and what kind should i expect from these two broken teeth on the big plate, and close together as well:
[image]

Comment: The picture isn't loading for me so I'm not putting this as an answer, but "two broken teeth close together" sound like shift gates/ramps. These are teeth which are close together but shaped differently to aide shifting.

Comment: Looks like you hit a curb with the ring, or some such.  But there are two relatively complete teeth between the two missing ones, so the situation is not nearly as dire as it would be with two adjacent teeth gone.  I would expect some difficulty shifting onto that ring, but no problems otherwise unless you cross-chain pretty badly, in which case the chain could drop off of that ring (or jam, it the gods hate you).

Comment: That ring has seen better days. I've certainly ridden some that were more sharky but if your problem-rings are more deformed that might explain things.

Comment: Does it work?  If it works, don't fix it.  If not, buy a new chain ring.  Having seen this, I would imagine that every problem shifting was caused by the broken teeth (which may well not be true).  If you are like me in this respect, you need a new chain ring.

Comment: I would be afraid of broken teeth syndrome. Your teeth. I would change it.

Answer (score 3):

The only issues will be directly observed, i.e. either it will mis-shift, over-shift/drop the chain, or not. These don't look like proper ramp teeth which do resemble broken ones, except they're usually spaced 2 or 4 evenly around the ring. The wear looks advanced enough that you really have no excuse not to just get another new or less worn ring and avoid problems.