# New chain, skipping off small sprocket in front when under load

Tags: chain, skipping

[image]Got a new chain, for ten speed rear cassette. Slightly shorter than old chain, but can still reach large sprocket, large cassette ring, although tight.  Skipping off small sprocket in front under load.  Is there an adjustment possible or do I need a new front sprocket?

Comment: If the new chain is indeed shorter then you either need a new front sprocket or some maintenance on your rear derailer.

Comment: How old (mileage) was the previous chain? How's the mileage of the ring? New chain & old rings don't marry well. Check if the teeth have become shark teeth.

Comment: Post a picture of the front small chainring (what you called a sprocket).  A picture from the left side of the bike so the tooth profile is easy to see.  See this question for an example: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/429/does-this-chainring-need-to-be-replaced

Answer (score 1):

The small chainring in your picture looks fairly worn - not bad but not good.

I can't see much of the big chainring to make a judgement there.

Here's a silhouette of a sector of new chainring, with this one piece mirrored left-for-right.

[image]

Compare this with yours:

[image]

The top photo has a definite "up and to the right" look while the flipped second image has a "up and to the left" look.
its not a straight-on photo but you get the idea.

As a test, you can **try** flipping the chainring, but this will mess up the horizontal offset so can't really be ridden like this with indexed gears.  If you have friction gears this may work.   Also the chainring bolts may not seat very well against the other side - this is only a suggestion to help test the wear of the chainring teeth.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to teach me what to look for.  I will investigate flipping it.  Thanks again.